# cosets aren't forming a partition?

Tags: abstract-algebra, set-partition

If you have a group $G$ and $H \leq G$, the cosets of $H$ should partition $G$.

Suppose $G=\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_4$ and $H=\langle (0,1)\rangle = \{(0,0), (0,1),(0,2),(0,3)\}$. Then both  $(1,1)+H$ and $(1,2)+H$ contain $(1,3)$. What am I doing that's dumb?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing. Indeed

$$(1,2)+H=(1,1)+H\Longleftrightarrow (1,2)-(1,1)\in H$$

Remember: $\,xH=yH\Longleftrightarrow x^{-1}y\in H\,$ , or additively: $\,x+H=y+H\Longleftrightarrow -x+y\in H\,$

Comment: I got confused because the two cosets don't contain the same elements. $(1,0)$ is not in $(1,2)+H$, but is in $(1,1)+H$.

Comment: $(1,2)+(0,2)=(1,0)$ ;)

Comment: @rick , N.S. already answered you. It seems like you forgot you're workimg modulo 2 in the left coordinate and modulo 4 in the right one.